# How to SELECT DISTINCT one column and ORDER by another column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id |  domain  | domain_date           | domain_status  |
1  |abc_com   | 2022-08-20 15:42:35   |       1        |
2  |def_com   | 2022-08-20 15:44:31   |       1        |
3  |def_com   | 2022-08-20 15:40:05   |       1        |
4  |abc_com   | 2022-08-20 15:35:05   |       0        |
5  |ghi_com   | 2022-08-20 15:25:05   |       1        |
6  |ghi_com   | 2022-08-20 15:25:00   |       1        |
7  |abc_com   | 2022-08-19 15:22:00   |       1        |
8  |ghi_com   | 2022-08-20 15:25:05   |       1        |
9  |abc_com   | 2022-08-20 15:21:00   |       1        |
10 |abc_com   | 2022-08-19 15:21:20   |       1        |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to get latest entries of five records from the table but I don't want duplicate domains.
I tried with SELECT DISTINCT, Distinct works fine if I select only domain it cuts the duplicates but if selects two columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT domain, domain_date FROM Domains
```

It still shows duplicates because the dates are different

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: Do you need the latest record per domain for upto 5 domains? Or do you need to get record per domain from the latest 5 records?

Answer (score 0):

if you group on max domain date, you will get a distinct list of domains with their max domain_date:

```
select 
    domain, max(domain_date) as MaxOfDomainDate
from table
group by domain
```

We can join the table on this result set if we want to get the status that goes with the domain record for that date:

```
select A.domain, A.domain_date, A.domain_status
from
table A
inner join
(
    select 
        domain, max(domain_date) as MaxOfDomainDate
    from table
    group by domain
) B
on A.domain = B.domain
and A.domain_date = B.domain_date;
```

You should be able to add ordering and TOP or LIMIT to such a query pretty easily to get the "latest 5" and so on (I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader ;) )

Answer (score -1):

I think that you may want domain_date values to be unique.

```
SELECT DISTINCT domain WHERE domain_date UNIQUE
```